# PHP session not working after setting secure httponly

Tags: php, apache, security, httponly

Friends,

I have a testing web server with Apache 2.2, with valid SSL certificate and PHP sessions are working fine on it.
As part of security recommendations I have set `Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure` entry in httpd.conf the sessions are not working now. Whenever I comment this entry it is working properly. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure below configurations in httpd.conf

LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so

```
<IfModule php5_module>
php_flag session.cookie_httponly on
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Roshin, I tried your suggestion but did not work